# Cast parameter pack values at runtime depending on some metadata

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have put together a class to handle cross platform loading of shared libs (LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress on Windows and dlopen/dlsym on Linux). The Call function looks like this -

```
template <typename ReturnT, typename... Args>
ReturnT Call(const std::string& name, Args... args)
{
        void* functionAddress = GetFunctionAddress(name);

        typedef ReturnT(CALLING_CONVENTION * variadicFunctionPointer)(Args...);

        auto functionPointer = reinterpret_cast<variadicFunctionPointer>(functionAddress);
        const auto returnValue = (*functionPointer)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

        return returnValue;
}
```

Usage is as follows -

```
 Library someLib("someLib.dll");

 auto ret = someLib.Call<bool>("SomeCall", "StringParam", 1, true, nullptr, nullptr);
```

This works nicely, but where I'm stuck is trying to cast each param dynamically at runtime.  I want to take some json, load the relevant lib, cast each param (we know the param type from the json) and then make the call.

```
 auto result = someLib.Call<bool>(function,
        std::stoi(params.at(0)["value"].get<std::string>()),
        reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(params.at(1)["value"].get<std::string>().c_str()),
        std::stoi(params.at(2)["value"].get<std::string>()),
        digest.data(),
        &bufferSize);
```

I've tried using a conversion function on each param pack arg, but that won't work because it requires different return types.

Is this possible using C++14?

Comment: You cannot really pass `nullptr`, as I doubt than your function expect `std::nullptr_t`.

Comment: `std::variant` with `std::visit` in C++17 might help, for C++14, you might look at boost version.

Comment: @Jarod42 I tried C++17 variant and can build a vector of all the required params and correct types, but then when I pass to my call function I of course need to call get to pass the underlying values.  Tried with a visitor, but it requires all potential invocations to have the same type and value category :(

Comment: Answer added. Tell me if it doesn't fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

With `std::variant` (C++17), you might do something like:

```
template <typename Ret>
struct Caller
{
    Caller(const std::string& name) : name(name) {}

    template <typename ... Ts>
    Ret operator ()(Ts... args) const
    {
        void* functionAddress = GetFunctionAddress(name);

        using Func =  Ret(Ts...);

        auto functionPointer = reinterpret_cast<Func*>(functionAddress);
        return (*functionPointer)(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }

    std::string name;
};
```

And then:

```
// Variant constructed from json
std::variant<int, std::string> s{"Hello"};
std::variant<int, std::string> a{40};
std::variant<int, std::string> b{2};

std::visit(Caller<void>("print"), s);
std::cout << std::visit(Caller<int>("add"), a, b) << std::endl;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86331fb5b073ecdc)

Comment: Thanks!  With a variant with 5 types and passing 5 params, I get a "compiler is out of heap space" error.  I'm thinking I might go down the libffi route or write a script to just generate "bindings" from our headers.